# Magento Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception [HTTP] Internal Server Error

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap, wsdl

```
$options = array(
'stream_context'=>stream_context_create(
    array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer'=> false,
            'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        )
    )
),
"trace" => 1,
"exception" => 0
);
$testClient = new SoapClient($apiHost.'/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $testClient->login($apiUser,$apiPass);
```

After this request I got the following error

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error

from phpinfo on host server I can see

**Soap Client   *enabled***

**Soap Server   *enabled***

Also I've tried with v2_soap, the result was the same.

I've compared Magento Core API configurations with another Magento instance where it works and they are same.

What else I check to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your script in try-catch block and catch `\SoapFault` exceptions, which are generated by `\SoapClient`, then you should be able to see exception message:

```
  try {
      $session = $testClient->login($apiUser, $apiPass);
  } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: After wrapping my script into try-catch block I got 
"Internal Server Error"

Comment: Then you need to check error logs on Magento side

Comment: I can't find any information about soap request. But I've seen messages connected instance update, and RedsysAPI.php.
Could this be a reason for that error?

Comment: Remove all logs on Magento side, execute your script and check newly created logs. 500 error usually means some uncaught exception on server side, so could be anything.

Comment: Currently problem has solved by the following change in app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php 

->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset)

to

->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset, true) Is there a way to fix it without touching core?